# Spring AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Show error on JSF page

Tags: spring, jsf, asynchronous

My email-sending code (a Spring managed bean) is executed asychronous (using Springs @Async Annotation) because our email-server seems rather slow (takes 3-4 seconds until the mail is sent). The email method throws an checked excpetion if the email cannot be sent.

Now I'm sending emails from my JSF-managed bean (i.e. my controller), e.g. to send credentials to newly created users and want to show a growl Message to inform the (admin-)user that the email sending code threw an excpetion (I know that there will be a delay, but thats seems ok as it does not block the gui thread).

What I've done so far:

I implemented my custom AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler, i.e. the method:

```
public class CustomAsyncExceptionHandler  implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

@Override
public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
// inform user that something went wrong (growl message)
}
```

}

This handler is then specified in Spring's XML config:

```
    <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="org.myproject.util.CustomAsyncExceptionHandler" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="asyncExecutor" scheduler="asyncScheduler" exception-handler="exceptionHandler" />
    <task:executor id="asyncExecutor" pool-size="5" />
    <task:scheduler id="asyncScheduler" pool-size="10" /
```

The problem is that I cannot access the FacesContext in this exceptionHandler (which is a spring-managed bean).

How can I do this and if not, is there another way to let the user know that  the async method threw an excpetion?

Comment: @BalusC  It was my first idea how to do it, but meanwhile I don't expect it to work like that. What I expect is that there is another solution, maybe working with listeners/callbacks, but I don't know if thats possible with spring's Async

Comment: i will address "if not, is there another way to let the user know that the async method threw an excpetion?" If you use PrimeFaces, you need to save the success or failure of sending emails in a EmailTransactions table with columns such as to, cc, failurereason, status, numberOfTries, etc. Then use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml with a reasonable interval attribute and update a part of the admin page